# PlayStation 4 video drops when connected to Dell monitor via HDMI-to-DisplayPort adapter

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I'm trying to get my PS4 connected to my Dell monitor which has a DisplayPort input. I've purchased an [HDMI-to-DisplayPort adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JQORLCG) and a [DisplayPort cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7RP2QQ) in order to do so. This works, but the video cuts out periodically.

Sometimes, I can get a good 30-45 minutes in before the monitor goes black for about 2 seconds. Then, everything is back to normal again for a while longer. Other times, this happens more frequently (like every 2-3 minutes). This is extremely frustrating and makes most games unplayable.

I have a computer connected to the same monitor, and it exhibits no such issue. I recognize my setup is a bit odd, and I suspect the adapter may be the culprit. Has anyone dealt with a similar problem? Do you have any suggestions for what I could try or how I could fix this (short of buying a television)?

Comment: Is this a powered adapter? I have similar problems with my HDMI splitter, sometimes turning it off/on fixes it, or un/replugging the culprit monitor

Comment: @BenBrocka It is powered off USB. It doesn't have a power switch, but I will try unplugging/reconnecting the power. I have noticed that it seems to work just as well without the power connected at all, which seems a little strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a reliable solution to this problem.

My converter was powered by USB. I got a powered USB hub and used it to power my HDMI-to-DisplayPort converter thinking maybe it wasn't getting enough power from the USB port on my monitor, but that didn't make a difference.

I probably could have tried the one other video converter I found on eBay (It appears not many people make these things. Not even Monoprice carries one.) to see if that gave better results, but I decided it wasn't worth the hassle.

I ended up returning the PS4 and all the peripherals.

Comment: I'm only just seeing this question...I haven't actually tried a setup like this but professionally I see *tons* of problems with lousy DisplayPort adapters.  I'd bet money that's all it was and bet a good active converter (even unpowered, although that might work better doing the conversion the other direction) would have fixed matters, or in the worst case (since it sounds like there aren't many of these) going to DVI instead...HDMI to DVI cables are quite plentiful and I'm assuming a monitor with DP in also supports DVI in.  And some newer DP 1.2 monitors can be...touchy.

Comment: @Shinrai Thanks for the feedback. I considered going to DVI, but that's how my computer is connected to the monitor. Then, I was going to either be swapping cables or getting some sort of switch. I, like you, suspect it's just a crappy adapter, but I wasn't willing to try the other adapter I found. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you need a hdmi to DP not the one you have as it connects in a odd way to the dp or just get a hdmi to dp cable an active type will be better

Comment: If you're going to say he has the wrong one, what *should* he look for?  Active type doesn't really tell anyone a whole lot.

Comment: @blazedragon As best I can tell, there *isn't* an HDMI to DP cable. I know this because I bought a DP to HDMI cable at first before I bought the adapter/cable setup I have now. Found out that cable is not bi-directional. It only does DP to HDMI but not the other way around.

Comment: Hdmi to DVI connections are about $20AU. Works fine. Try droping the resolution.